# Wrap (-wrap) equivalent in Visual studio

Tags: c, visual-studio, linker

is there an equivalent function as the -wrap option in GCC to replace symbols in visual studio.

I have to mock one function in a large module and I would like not to change the productive code.

Comment: In Visual Studio, they normally do it using #defines at the compile stage; not during the linking stage.

Comment: Thanks, but this solution has the uggly side effect, that the productive code "knows" about the test code.

Comment: You could use gcc on Windows.